# how to hide parent div, keeping inner div visible?

Tags: css, html

Below is a simplified version of my problem. Considering the following piece of HTML:

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none">  
  text i do not want  
  <div id="div2" style="display:block">  
    text i want to keep  
  </div>  
</div>
```

But of course, "*text i want to keep*" will not be displayed because the
parent div is not visible.

**Question:** How do you only dispaly the content of the inner div?

Due to the widget blogger uses, I have no access to the code and need to clear the outer div with some CSS. I have already ruled out `font-size: 0;` after reading [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/fonts/qt/tipfont0.htm). Messing with negative margins too is ruled out, due to position of elements.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
color: transparent;
background: transparent;
```

of course, that won't actually make the text non-selectable, just non-visible.

Really what you're trying to do is sort of against the box-model concept, and it'd be better if you were able to enclose the text you didn't want to see in a separate div of equal level to the one you do want to see, and then hide that other div, i.e.

```
<div id="div1">  
  <div id="div3" style="display:none">text i do not want</div>
  <div id="div2" style="display:block">  
    text i want to keep  
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I think he's aware of the fact that changing the HTML would fix this, but "Due to the widget blogger uses, [he has] no access to the code"

Comment: Hence the "if you were able" - I recognize that such might not be possible for his circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the hierarchical nature of HTML, this is a hard nut to crack. The common solution is to move one element out of the other and style them so that they appear to be nested, but I assume you cannot do that in this case.

The only solution I can think of that will nullify the parent element while keeping the child element is absolute positioning, but that will be hard if you've got dynamic heights/widths on the elements.

But try this:

```
#div1 {
    /* You might want to set a height here appropriate for #div2 */
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -10000px;
}

#div2 {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want just the text to disappear or the space that the text takes up to collapse too?

If you just want the text to disappear, use

```
<div id="div1" style="text-indent:-9999px;">
   text i do not want
   <div id="div2" style="text-indent:0">
     text i want to keep
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this it helped me

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    background: #fff;
    font-size:100&#37;;
}
#hide {
    visibility:hidden;
}
#show {
    visibility:visible
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hide"> hide this text
    <div id="show"> show this text </div>
    hide this text too </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the 'Text I do not want' in another DIV or SPAN with display:none style.