# Hiding parent div but keep children divs visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got showable div called "Toolbox", inside it i got separate "tools" - dragable divs with some icons and input fields for little notes.

I want to show toolbox, grab selected tools, drag it out the toolbox and drop where it need to be (this dragable divs need to be in right places for print, it's not saved anyway). This step was easy and i got it already.

Now I want to hide back toolbox with his tools but keep dragged out tools still visible! How to do this?

-------- edit ------

Somwhere out of toolbox

```
<a href="#toolbox" onclick="showmydiv('toolbox");">Show toolbox</a>
```

Then toolbox

```
<div id="toolbox" style="display:none;">
<a href="#toolbox" onclick="hidemydiv('toolbox");">Hide toolbox</a>
 <div class="draggable" id="tool1"><img src="tool1icon.png"><input value="" id="tool1label"></div>
 <div class="draggable" id="tool2"> ...
  ... more tools
</div>
```

I got working functions in separate js file for dragging showing and hiding - it's not a problem - i need to remove cascading hiding from children.

----- edit2 ----

Of course i have been here - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

But it's not the solution i got working drag function, and i cannot specify new containers where to drop - dragable divs just stay where mouse key is released. Let's put this aside.

More important is how to release children from parent to not inherit parent (hiding) style and parent events? Any ideas, directions where to search?

---- eedit 3 -------

Been there - [how to hide parent div, keeping inner div visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232147/how-to-hide-parent-div-keeping-inner-div-visible) - so still no solution

Comment: What research have you done into this?  Have you any existing code to show us that you've worked on so far?  You've not really given us enough information to go on with - maybe post a fiddle to demonstrate where you're stuck?

Comment: Edited the question with all i got. I cannot use jquery, cannot  go into @media-print to hide toolbox from printing.
I know that ss long tools are inside toolbox they inherit all styles from toolbox. I don't know how to move them out in DOM tree.

Comment: @Daedalus - i wrote that i got my working functions for drag, show and hide divs - never stated that there are native. 
I only understand that children must be move out from parent - not only in browser view but also in code.
I's not a matter of current js functions. Maybe new function onDrop event can be written.

Comment: @Daedalus - "explain how you expect to hide a container but not the children?" - if i knew it i wouldn't asking here... 
Another edit. Never asked for code but for idea, directions for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

A) change the parent for the moved children (for example create absolutely positioned div as child of body)

B) create duplicates and hide originals

Comment: I'm gonna go into dynamically created divs with js out of this toolbox, in toolbox will be just images with anchors and onClick events. Created tools will be inside another container and usable as needed.