# How do I hide the parent of a nested list while keeping the nested list visible?

Tags: html, css

I want to hide the parent of a nested list while keeping the nested list visible. In addition, I do not want the parent to take up any space on the page when it is hidden.

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="parent">Menu
        <ul class="nested">
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS Attempt 1

```
.parent {
    display: none;
}
.nested {
    display: block;
}
```

I could not get the nested items to show using this method.

### CSS Attempt 2

```
.parent {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.nested {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

The parent still took up space on the page, even though you could not see it.

Is there a third option or will I have to use visibility and change the margins on the nested list?

A similar question was asked here [how to hide parent div, keeping inner div visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232147/how-to-hide-parent-div-keeping-inner-div-visible) but I want to make sure that there isn't a more appropriate/accurate answer than the ones proposed there (e.g. move one element out of the other) and here (use visibility).

Comment: This sort of functionality is best left to JS.

Comment: Could you give me a little sample of JS as guidance? I'm not that comfortable with it but I'm sure I could figure it out with a bit of help. If I use hidden() on the parent and show() on the children, would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @paulie_D has mentioned in the comments above, you can't achieve this with CSS although you can use JavaScript to pull the element out or duplicate it and then show it. Here's an example:

```js
var element = jQuery('.nested').clone();
element.appendTo('ul');
```

```css
.parent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="parent">Menu
    <ul class="nested">
      <li>About</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am cloning `.nested` using the [jQuery .clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) function and appending it to the only visible item on the page i.e. the `<ul>`. You can also append it to any other visible item on your page as per your wish.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the exact effect you are looking for, but you can do this with CSS in certain situations by positioning the parent off screen and then positioning the child back on screen.  Something like this:

```
.parent { position:absolute; top:-9999px;}
.nested { position:absolute; top:9999px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a better pure 100% css solution.

1. Embed the list tree using div
2. Rest styling for UL
3. Style only the top level UL (`div > ul {}`)
4. Show/hide LIs basing on additional UL class like `.active`